# Custom days to file Customer.subscription.trial_will_end Event from stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe.net

I want to know that how I can setup stripe to add custom days that subscription.trial_will_end fire as it fires on 3 days before trial end.

so How I can setup it to before 1 day when trial ends.

Thanks
Dalvir

Answer (score 1):

There is unfortunately no way to do this with Stripe's webhooks at the moment and that event will only fire 3 days before the end of the trial period.

If you want to detect this 1 day before you would need to store the date at which the trial period ends in your database and then have a [CRON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job running on your server each day for example, checking if you have any trial period ending the next day and if so reach out to your customers for example.